# No entry in the multicast RIB while PIM join is present

Tags: juniper, multicast, juniper-mx

I have a router which receives multicast traffic from the source over a multicast LSP([signaled by LDP](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/mpls/topics/ref/statement/p2mp-edit-protocols-ldp.html)):

```
root@PE3> show pim join detail                  
Instance: PIM.master Family: INET
R = Rendezvous Point Tree, S = Sparse, W = Wildcard

Group: 232.1.1.1
    Source: 10.1.1.10
    Flags: sparse,spt
    Upstream protocol: MLDP
    Upstream interface: Pseudo MLDP           
    Downstream neighbors:
        Interface: ge-0/0/3.0             
        Interface: ge-0/0/1.0 (assert winner)

Instance: PIM.master Family: INET6
R = Rendezvous Point Tree, S = Sparse, W = Wildcard

root@PE3>
```

As seen above, the `Upstream interface` is `Pseudo MLDP`.

I can confirm the multicast traffic on the MPLS core-facing interface with packet capture:

```
00:42:19.767009 02:06:04:0e:ff:f0 > 02:06:06:0e:ff:f0, ethertype MPLS unicast (0x8847), length 102: MPLS (label 300720, exp 0, [S], ttl 97)
        (tos 0x0, ttl 98, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.1.1.10 > 232.1.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 30014, seq 11171, length 64
```

Those packets are routed via `ge-0/0/1.0` as they should:

```
root@PE3> show route forwarding-table label 300720                    
Routing table: default.mpls
MPLS:
Destination        Type RtRef Next hop           Type Index    NhRef Netif
300720             user     0                    indr  1048577     2
                                                 comp      631     1

Routing table: __mpls-oam__.mpls
MPLS:
Enabled protocols: Bridging, Single VLAN, Dual VLAN, 
Destination        Type RtRef Next hop           Type Index    NhRef Netif
default            perm     0                    dscd      545     1

root@PE3>
```

However, they should also be routed via the `ge-0/0/3.0` as seen in the output of `show pim join detail`, but there is not even an entry in the `inet.1` table for `232.1.1.1,10.1.1.10/64`:

```
root@PE3> show route table inet.1 

inet.1: 3 destinations, 3 routes (3 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

224.0.0.0/4        *[Multicast/180] 05:10:43
                      MultiResolve
224.0.0.0/24       *[Multicast/180] 05:10:43
                      MultiDiscard
232.0.0.0/8        *[Multicast/180] 05:10:43
                      MultiResolve

root@PE3>
```

Interfaces `ge-0/0/3.0` and `ge-0/0/1.0` are connected to different broadcast domains and in both broadcast domains there are listeners subscribed to `232.1.1.1`.

What might cause such behavior?

Comment: Are you using PIM SSM or PIM ASM?

Comment: I'm using PIM SSM.